# How do I read from or save to an avro file containing '\00' character in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, avro

I am trying to load the contents of an avro file as string in Java (Eclipse) so that I can edit it. But when I load the file the line after `\00` is removed. Same thing occurs when I try to save the string containing `\00` to an avro file. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: You might need to open the file as binary

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. I tried it using "byte[] fileContents =  Files.readAllBytes(path)". But when I execute "System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fileContents))" all I am getting is an array of numbers. I need to display the content of avro as it is so that I can edit it.

Comment: Its not a good idea to edit a binary file in string format.Try new String(bytes), not sure how well it will work on \00

Comment: It suffers from the same problem. The line after \00 gets deleted.

Comment: Why don't you use GenericRecord for parsing the avro file?

Comment: I did that for getSchema function. But can we read the entire content of avro file to a string variable using GenericRecord? If so please show me how, I am stuck.

Comment: `\00` is normally the string terminate character - are you sure this is string data?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Here is a section in the avro file which contains this and other such characters. "null\00\E9g\98\A0\EA ?fq\F1\".